# Could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Tags: mysql, spring

I am receving a blocker when i tried to run a simple spring boot mysql crud operation.To give you a gist I have a simple jsp home page where i have a register button which navigates to Register page which has a form with one text box and one button called submit.. On click of submit button the values from the form should be pushed to the database. The issue that i'm facing is and error when i tried to click on submit button in register page. Please take alook on the code to have better understanding.

I was doing postmapping and tried to save the data using repository.save() crud operation using @requestbody annotation to create the object.. but doing so gave me the following error

```
"There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported".
```

Controller :

```
package com.kaushik.Megamart.Controllers;

import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.kaushik.Megamart.model.Register;
import com.kaushik.Megamart.repository.RegisterRepository;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private RegisterRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homepage()

    {
        System.out.println("In Home page");
        return "home.jsp";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerpage()
    {
        System.out.println("In register page");
        return "regist.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping(path ="/regi")
    public String savedata(@Valid Register ex) {
         repository.save(ex);
         System.out.println("Entered function");

        return "success.jsp";
    }
}
```

POJO(Register.java):

```
package com.kaushik.Megamart.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Register {

@Id
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
        public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

regist.jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Registration</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form  action="/regi" method="post"> 
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>User Name :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

RegisterRepository.java :

```
package com.kaushik.Megamart.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.kaushik.Megamart.model.Register;

public interface RegisterRepository extends JpaRepository<Register, String> {

}
```

Expected : I want the data from the register form to be pushed to the database.

Actual : Reciving error on clicking submit button in register page.

```
Error :There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: In controller class which method is used for posting to database ? And are you posting any Non-English character ?

Comment: I have just used Request Mapping annotation and haven't specified either get or post in controller. But if u take a look at my JSP page I have mentioned that the request method is POST. I'm not posting any Non-English char all i'm passing is a sample string.

Comment: Btw I was able to find the root cause and resolve this issue. In the controller when I was requesting for /register I  had to create a model attribute for the particular POJO and use the same in my JSP. This solved my above issue

Comment: @GetMapping("/register")
 public String registerpage(@ModelAttribute("register") Register reg,ModelMap model)
 {
  System.out.println("In register page");
  return "regist.jsp";
 }